# New default message for custom Off-Topic close reason

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I voted to close a question as Off-Topic today. It was homework dump. I typically (blindly) just change

> This question is off-topic because it is about

to

> This question is off-topic because it is a code writing request.

and submit. But, after submitting, I saw that my message was

> I think this may be off-topic because a code writing request.

So the default message was changed.

What is the rationale behind the change? Are we trying to be "nicer" in the way we express ourselves, giving our opinion rather than stating it as a fact? Have there been too many wrong close votes?

Comment: @AndrewMedico Sweet, thanks! The recommendation at the top is new too.

Comment: Actually, the question is kind of different. I'd like to know why the change happened, unless that's implied by the suggested one.